# Update all installed packages except kernels

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to create a state that will update all the installed packages except Kernels.
I have the following state that updates all the installed packages:

```
common_uptodate:
  pkg.uptodate:
    - refresh: True
    - order: last
```

However, it does not support the `exclude` flag.

Does anyone have a solution to do something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your minion's are using APT as a package manager, i would suggest to use the saltstack module [aptpkg](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.aptpkg.html#salt.modules.aptpkg.hold) with the "hold" function.
You could try to use it like that:

```
run_pkg_hold:
  module.run:
    - name: pkg.hold
    - pkgs: kernelpackages...
```

You could use an workaround by running the specific package hold command on the minion, using cmd.run: (as your upgrade will be be performed at last there should be no problem)

```
run_pkg_hold:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'apt-mark hold <pkg-name>'
```

It depends on which OS your minion got.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Centos 7 and I have tested out the yum version, but pkg.hold doesn't behave as I would expect.

```run_pkg_hold:
  module.run:
    - name: pkg.hold
    - pkgs: kernel

common_uptodate:
  pkg.uptodate:
    - refresh: True
    - order: last```

Results in holding a package for each letter in the word kernel.

Comment: Try to add single quotes on package name.